# Stream from HTTPS to Google Cloud Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to stream the "ReadableStream" from `fetch` api in a Google Cloud function into a bucket?

It seems getReader() returns one from http response from fetch. createReadStream and 
`createWriteStream();
localReadStream.pipe(remoteWriteStream);`

Supposed to pipe streams from bucket => fs => fs to bucket (or new file in different bucket), but AFAIK Cloud Functions does not allow local file access, right?

How does one stream from one to a bucket?

Comment: Have you had a look at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming?

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const CLOUD_BUCKET = 'MY_BUCKET_NAME'
const storage = Storage({
  projectId: 'MY_PROJECT_NAME'
});
const bucket = storage.bucket(CLOUD_BUCKET);
fetch(url).then( response => {
  let remoteWriteStream = bucket.file('zebra.png').createWriteStream();
  response.body.pipe(remoteWriteStream);
})
```

Basically pipe the body itself.